# cookies are not sending to the server in nextjs

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

i have a nextjs app and I'm using expressjs and graphql in backend.
On my ssr page I'm doing:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const id = ctx.query.slug[1]
    const ad = await fetchCarAd(id, ctx)

    return {
        props: {
            .
            .
            .
        },
    }
}
```

fetchCarAd finally goes here:

```js
    const response = await axios(getGraphqlUrl, {
        data: data,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    })
```

in backend i'm doing:

```js
const canBookmarkAd = async (parent, args, context) => {
    const user = await ejectUserFromReq(context)
    .
    .
    .
}
```

```js
export const ejectUserFromReq = async (context) => {
    const token = context.cookies && context.cookies.token ? context.cookies.token : null
    if (!!!token) {
        return null
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here cookies is empty even when i can see the cookie in chrome developer tools > application > storage or when i navigate to this page from other next pages.

but if i eject cookie from nextjs context and pass to axios as header, it works fine.

```js
    // here ctx is comming from nextjs.
    const cookie = ctx ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : null;
    const response = await axios(getGraphqlUrl, {
        data: data,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'CSRF-Token': getCsrfTokenFromDom(),
            'Cookie': cookie || ''
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    })
```

this solution works but gives us the following error:

[image]

because cookie is a [forbidden headername](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)

this happens only in **getServerSideProps**. if i send request after that cookies work fine and there is no need to add cookie to headername.

Anyone knows why cookies are empty or what is the correct way to send cookies in **getServerSideProps**?.